# NSString getCString doesn't populate array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to convert a `NSString` to a `char*` using this code:

```
char *key = (char*) calloc(kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1, sizeof(char));
[keyString getCString:key maxLength:(kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
char* cstring = [keyString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < (kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1); ++i)
{
  NSLog(@"MDO::key[%d] = %d", i, (int)key[i]);
  NSLog(@"MDO::cstring[%d] = %d", i, (int)cstring[i]);
}
```

However, when I run this, the contents of the `key` array are all 0 while the `cstring` contains the correct values.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which are the values of kCCKeySizeAES128 and keyString? Did you tray to put a breakpoint and see the value of `key` before the for loop?

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `getCString:maxLength:encoding:`? It returns a `BOOL` indicating success or failure and the docs cover the reasons for failure.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about how the `maxLength` argument is interpreted.  I assumed that it meant "copy at most `maxLength` chars into the array regardless of how long the original string is."  That is wrong.  `keyString` is longer than `kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1` so the method was returning `NO` and the `key` array remained zeroed out.  The solution is to use a `maxLength` that matches the original string length.